# At least one output file must be specified ffmpeg

Tags: video, files, ffmpeg, output

```
 ffmpeg -i oceans.mov -an -c:v libx264 -r 24 -preset fast \
   -profile:v baseline -g 64 -keyint_min 64 -b:v:0 230k -maxrate 250k -s:v:0 304x128 \
   -x264opts pic-struct:no-scenecut -movflags frag_keyframe -f ismv oceans-250k.ismv
```

The error is:

```
At least one output file must be specified.
```

We have an mp4 file, we want to have separate bitrates for that file. When we used this command as specified in [Creation of the Unified Streaming VOD pack](http://docs.unified-streaming.com/tutorials/vod/vodpack-creation.html), that's the error we get.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show the **complete** console output from your command.

Comment: I hade the same issue, i was using external url as input and after wrapping external url in quotes it worked fine. eg. `ffmpeg -i "https://test/test.mp"` worked. Input url was pretty long and it had all the special character than url can have. so i think it was messing up the command. try wrapping input file name or url in quotes

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command without the backslashes (`\`), as these may be causing issues on the command line of your shell. The backslashes are used to denote command continuation onto another line, but if you are copying and pasting, then extra tabs and spaces can get picked up. Try using the following one line example:

```
ffmpeg -i oceans.mov -an -c:v libx264 -r 24 -preset fast -profile:v baseline -g 64 -keyint_min 64 -b:v:0 230k -maxrate 250k -s:v:0 304x128 -x264opts pic-struct:no-scenecut -movflags frag_keyframe -f ismv oceans-250k.ismv
```

It is not as neatly presented in documentation, i.e. with the scroll bar, but lends itself better to copy and paste.

Your previous command, may only have been `ffmpeg -i oceans.mov -an -c:v libx264 -r 24 -preset fast` (with the rest after the first `\` being discarded by the shell), and as that contains no filename at the end, then that is why you would have received the error message that you did.

Comment: I tried after taking \ out, still same error

Comment: @TRD - Did using the line that I provided above give the same error also? Does the input file (_ocean.mov_) exist? Try a simpler, or the simplest, version of the command with all the options stripped out, does that work? For example `ffmpeg -i oceans.mov -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ab 64k -ar 48000 -vn -f ismv oceans-64k.isma`. Then add the (other) options one by one. My guess is an extraneous _invisible_ character has been copied, such as a non-break space or a line separator, or a wrong hyphen. I will test this myself when I finish work. Let me know how you get on.